# Thread in runnable state 900 seconds for no reason

Tags: java, oracle, multithreading, tomcat, spring-batch

I'm issuing some problems with application deployed on tomcat. It is actually servlet based SOAP web service.

Tomcat is Apache Tomcat/7.0.47, deployed on Linux OS, with Oracle DB (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource  used).

Catalina OPTS are: `CATALINA_OPTS="-server -Xms8G -Xmx20G -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:ConcGCThreads=5 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70"`

In web service spring batch is used and thread pool job launcher with following parameters:

```
TE_CORE_POOL_SIZE=20
TE_MAX_POOL_SIZE=40
TE_QUEUE_CAPACITY=200
```

Spring batch version: 2.1.9.RELEASE

Spring: 3.1.3.RELEASE

Oracle: 11.1.0.6.0-Production+

Tomcat in server xml has executor defined as:

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="800" 
                acceptCount="140" minSpareThreads="80" maxSpareThreads="160"/>
```

**Problem:**

Sometimes threads are just in runnable state **for 15 mins without reason**. For example, in WS I have spring job launch:
[image]

I get log line:

> 2020-07-13 15:52:47.894/CEST DEBUG MdmWS - Time for process everything before launcher run 0h 0m 0s 15ms 188us 682ns

Now job should be started, and job is defined as tasklet, but actually it wait exactly 15 minutes before it starts as shown in spring batch log:

> 2020-07-13 16:08:16.390/CEST INFO  SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob:
> [name=wizard_du_generation_job]] launched with the following
> parameters ...

and as shown below:
[image]

> 2020-07-13 16:08:16.514/CEST DEBUG RegularCalculation - Getting DUs
> for calc session: 3058, 2/954//, , , 1593554400000 2020-07-13
> 16:23:45.316/CEST DEBUG RegularCalculation - DUs received for calc
> session: 3058

As you can see here in log times, it took 15 minutes to get to the tasklet, and then 15 minutes to get results from facade.

I am really not sure what can be issue here, it is not like server or tomcat had any memory issues at this moment. It simple happens sometimes. Maybe in 1 of 10 times, sometimes even worse. I cant find any timeout parameter set to 900 (seconds - 15 mins) or similar, so I am really confused here.

I got thread dump and got these, but still not sure what can be issue:

```
"threadPoolTaskExecutor-3" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe834001800 nid=0x3279 runnable [0x00007fe751eda000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:239)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:92)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:172)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:117)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:77)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1023)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:999)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:584)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:849)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1770)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1739)
        - locked <0x00000002e383bfa8> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:298)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:395)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:777)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:618)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at ...core.common.dao.BaseDao.getConnection(BaseDao.java:224)
        at ...core.common.dao.BaseDao.query(BaseDao.java:72)
        at ...core.rr.dao.PrimaryRegDao.getUsagePointResources(PrimaryRegDao.java:219)
        at ...core.rr.dao.PrimaryRegDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$28d69ecb.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
        at ...core.rr.dao.PrimaryRegDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5487459d.getUsagePointResources(<generated>)
        at ...core.rr.PrimaryRegFacadeImpl.getUsagePointResources(PrimaryRegFacadeImpl.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.getUsagePointResources(Unknown Source)
        at ...core.rr.validation.PrimaryRegRefDataCacheImpl.init(PrimaryRegRefDataCacheImpl.java:335)
        at ...core.rr.validation.PrimaryRegProcessor.init(PrimaryRegProcessor.java:166)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:150)
        - locked <0x000000031c6949a8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:125)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:291)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:190)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:74)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:293)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So as this one:

```
"catalina-exec-38" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000023ca800 nid=0x3291 runnable [0x00007fe751ad7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:239)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:92)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:172)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:117)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:77)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1023)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:999)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:849)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1770)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1739)
    - locked <0x00000002e40f0978> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:298)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:395)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:777)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:618)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:202)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:334)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:94)
    at ...ws.MainProcessingWebService.executeJob(MainProcessingWebService.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet.doPost(WSSpringServlet.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    - locked <0x00000002ea47d4a0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

It is strange problem, so I am not sure if description is enough, but any help is welcome.
```

Comment: Have you checked for blocked sessions in the db?

Comment: Nothing there, didn't even come to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, but still better than no answer.

I changed scope of dependency to oracle jdbc from compile to provided and that solved the problem.